# Replacement of text between two matches, from one file to the other

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So I have two files:

```
/etc/some/file1.xml
/etc/some/file1.xml_bck
```

These files are config files with bunch of directives in it (all in one line).
Content looks like this:

```
<SOMETHING>somehost.domain.com;192.123.123.124;SOMEHOST1.DOMAIN.UK</SOMETHING>
```

My goal is to replace all text which is between  and  from /etc/some/file1.xml with /etc/some/file1.xml_bck

I guess `sed` can do the trick but it's a bit above me.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I got such grep
cat file1.xml |grep -oP '(?<=SOMETHING>).*(?=</SOMETHING)' 
somehost.domain.com;192.123.123.124;SOMEHOST1.DOMAIN.UK

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of adding further details in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two files:

OLD:

```
<SOMETHING>xxxxxxxxxx</SOMETHING>
```

NEW:

```
<SOMETHING>yyyyyyyyyy</SOMETHING>
```

You can run:

```
$ subst=$(grep -o '<SOMETHING>.*</SOMETHING>' OLD)
$ sed -e "s~<SOMETHING>.*<\/SOMETHING>~${subst}~" NEW
<SOMETHING>xxxxxxxxxx</SOMETHING>
```

And that's assuming that `~` doesn't show up in the chunk of text that you want to copy. Sed allows you to use pretty much any character as a delimiter, so depending on the text it could be `,`, `?`, etc.